# C# Multi-level dictionary based class

Tags: c#, dictionary, multi-level

I'm planning to create a class representing a html table, problem is that it must be able to contain 3+ dimensions, one dimension will be the width of course, the rest will be along the length like this:

```
foo1:bar1
foo1:bar2
foo2:bar1
foo2:bar2

etc.
```

Now I'm contemplating how to represent this in my class, my idea is to use a multi-level dictionary, i.e. one that can be indexed like this: `myDict[fooKey][barKey][...]`, is that a good idea? Is it possible? How?

Can I let the user of the class give it any Dictionary along with an int depth and then cast to dictionary when using the class internally?

edit: Seems like I was a bit unclear, there is a practical depth limit obviously, but I'd prefer to code it for any depth, the depth should be given by the user of the class.

Comment: When you say *multi-level dictionary* do you mean something like `Dictionary<Key, Dictionary<OtherKey, Value>>`? This question is unclear.

Comment: Is there any limit on the depth?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to find a C# equivalent to the STL `multimap` class in C++. [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/multimap)'s a decent implementation from dotnetperils.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Dictionary with type of Key Dictionary...

so you can say:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary < string, string>> x;
```

and use it as mentioned of you..

```
x["asdf"]["asdf"] = "asdf";
```